# What if git submodule remote is deleted

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to use a remote git repo as a library in my project and thought about adding it as a submodule to my git repo but than I thought: What if the submodule repo will be deleted?
I sure would still have my local copy of it and could hop around in all the branches that I have locally but I never trust in anything that I have locally. Only what is on the server is what I  trust.
So if I ignore my "local backUp", the files would be lost in case that the remote server for the submodule isn't there anymore right? Or is there a mechanism for that?

So in that case I would be better of to copy the files from the submodule repo into my actual repo and commit all the files so that I actually have a copy of them on my server.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to include external repos that I basically just want to read and use?

Thanks for all suggestions! Highly appreciate it!

Comment: Fork it and use the forked repo as the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Use git subtree instead of submodule -> https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree

Comment: as far as I know the described issue isn't solved by using subtree instead of submodules. Their might be other reasons to prevere submodules over subtrees but if the remote of the used library disappears your left with nothing but the copy on your personal machine, right?

Comment: No - all the code and files are added into the main repository. It's not just a reference to a remote repo. https://gist.github.com/SKempin/b7857a6ff6bddb05717cc17a44091202

Comment: and no meta data is added either. So when updating a subtree, you will have to specify the remote. E.g. 
git subtree pull -P <folder name> <remote> <branch name> --squash

Comment: ok I gave it a try and it certainly works and actually does fullfill my above mentioned requirements. BUT! I don't whant to start a discussion about submodules vs. subtrees, but I feel like subtrees are way to static and there is to little information about them. I don't really understand what is the difference between a "subtree" and "downloading the files and committing it to your repo". In the latter I could at least add the remote git url to my commit which subtree doesn't do.

Thanks for the hint. Definitelly learned something new again but I think I prevere submodules. Personal opinion

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works for me. Any suggestion on how to make this better of course is still highly appreciated:

1. I opened up another repo on my server.
2. I cloned the library repo that I want to include as a submodule in a separate directory
3. Added my submodule repo server as a second remote in the dir of step 2
4. pushed the branches from the library repo to my submodule repo
5. included my submodule repo into my project as a submodule with the according branch

Seems a bit bulky but satisfies my paranoia.